# Remove Border From Smiles in Post

Tags: css

Hello i am finally getting to grips with CSS after about 4 years of picking it up as i go. This problem though has had me stumped for a few hours now so ive gave up and decided to ask for some help and learn from it that way.

All the smilies in my site have the img border that is for comment images.

examples here-
http://onlinebanter.com/node/5334

Ive already removed the border with border:none at other places in my website but i cant seem to change this. Could anyone suggest something for me?

thanks

Comment: have you tried: img {border:none} ?

Comment: See my answer below. In the future try using Firebug for Firefox or Inspect Element in Chrome. Both allow you to see exactly what css rules are being applied. Also allow you to change css rules directly in the browser... very helpful for debugging and trying different things.

Answer (score 1):

A quick inspect element using Firebug add-on for Firefox reveals this is because of the following rule in one of your css files.

```
#comments .b2-postcontent img {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    ...
}
```

Changing this to `border: none;` should fix this. Not sure if you are using a css file packager since the css file seems to be `css_9f04d02d9bb1b7bc07fd70d30ee1b762.css`. So maybe just search for `#comments .b2-postcontent img` in all files and then change the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

Thank mt. Im a big fan of firebug mt. This though has got me. Ive a feeling i might have tried your suggestion too. I think it removes the border from my comment image which isnt desired. I suppose then i would just have to target it that itself. Let me go try and thanks.

Thanks Wurst too. I think that just removes all my image borders. Maybe i have got it all set up at he wrong level. I will be right back.

Comment: as i thought changing #comments .b2-postcontent img has taken away my comment author pictures border too. I dont seem to be able to add a border either. This theme i have has the strangest css ive ever seen. Ive never had to use so many !important in all my days. Makes me wonder if i dont now about something else. Nothing i do seems to add a border to the comment image now.

Comment: In that case try adding another class to the smiley images. `<img class='smiley'../>`. Leave the original `#comments .b2-postcontent img` css class unchanged (with the border). Define a (more specific) css class `#comments .b2-postcontent img.smiley` that defines the border:none property. This should keep the border for the author pictures and remove them for smileys.

Comment: Thanks for your time mtariq. I dont seem to be able to add a class to my smileys mtariq. Im using drupal which is confusing things. The smiley module doesnt even have any css with it. I dont think its wrapping the smileys in a class. I can change the class for any images in content and then just add a border to the images. the code to take out all the clears etc is this. dunno if this is a long way of doing it .b2-article img, img.b2-article, .b2-block img, .b2-footer img {
  border:0 !important;
  clear:none !important;
  float:none !important;
  margin:3px;
}

Comment: 1- [This link](http://drupal.org/node/15950) might help. Also contains a link to a smileys with css module. 2- If does not help, maybe reverse the logic I gave above and add a `author` (or `border`) css class to the images you need a border around (if that is more under your control)?